# What to do when you have got nothing to do in office?

Tags: work-environment

Few months back, we got a project. In this project, Hardware team was responsible for designing its hardware and I was responsible for its software. Within a month I developed it software and was working fine as I have tested it on development boards.
I have also given a demo of it to my reporting manager and they knew that I am done with my job.

Now this hardware team is actually lagging. They have not  designed hardware till now. I can understand that its not easy to design hardware but the main problem is I don't have any work to do. I have discussed this with my reporting manager. I told them that till the hardware is ready give me some other work to do but all they are saying is just wait till hardware is ready. I have got nothing to do. All I do is google some new stuff and technology and learn them. I wonder this will eventually decrease my performance. I don't know what to do?
 Can anyone give me some advice on this kind of situation.?

Answer (score 4):

There is *always* something to do.

It's a perfect time to take some time off, whether it be a week's vacation, or simply a day to perform all those little home tasks you've been putting off.

It's a perfect opportunity to ensure you've completed all of the annual company training required, if any. Attend a free webinar offered by your software vendor. Study up on the hardware you're going to be coding for. Even it it is hardware being actually made by the team, there should be components that you can learn about.

You're a coder, pick a part of the language you use that you aren't comfortable coding, and learn more about it. Practice. Write up code snippets that you might be able to use. Think like you have been given the go ahead... what might you need to go out to Google to look up how to do. Look it up now and learn it, and write snippets. Even if it ends up not being needed, you've now got it in your personal portfolio.

When you do get the go ahead, you're likely going to be pushed to perform fast, since the other team caused delays (their inefficiency isn't your problem, until your boss makes it so.) Try to figure out everything you can, now, to prep for your own work when it comes.

Keep busy, keep happy, make it look like you're productive. Otherwise your company may start wondering why they've got you around now, before you're needed.

Comment: Nice answer. As you said, I started learning some new things related to my profession but I don't know what to say if some one from the higher authority ask me what are you doing?. Is it okay to tell them that I am learning something new for my ownself?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it doesn't sound too bad. Is this your first and only project at the place? As you said down time is best suited for corrections, refactoring, etc. I would go back and correct/fix things, read articles, etc. It's not that big of a deal but you can use this time to make sure you dotted all the i's and crossed all the t's so to speak.

If you told your boss/hardware team that you had nothing else to do and you are on standby, then it is understood that you have nothing to do. There's no real point to constantly bring this up as it would only irritate them.