# I finished my task, what to do now?

Tags: software-development

I have finished a little task that took 2 months to develop, but my boss is on vacation for 3 days.

I am planning to report that I am done to her via Skype chat and ask what to I should do next.

What I am going do?

Comment: Duplicate of several other "what should I do when I don't have anything to do" questions.  What you're gonna do is exactly what you said you were going to do -- ask her what's next. Or ask co-workers what you can help with. Or look around and find something useful to do. Or invest some time in improving skills that you expect to need. Or...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do when you have got nothing to do in office?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56711/what-to-do-when-you-have-got-nothing-to-do-in-office)

Answer (score 4):

Review your work done. Look if something is wrong or missing.
If nothing is wrong. Do something resourceful that will benefit you and your boss.
Sometimes. take time to take a rest.

Comment: She just told me what to do. I just study the next task (maybe my next task) and coding it so that she came back from a vacation/leave, I am done something not wasting time and do nothing. My co-workers are working and busy.